# Typo3: How can I pass dynamic data from typoscript to partial?

Tags: typo3, partial

I try to pass dynamic data from TypoScript to a Partial.

Is it possible and how can I do that?

**TS:**

```
lib.mydata = TEXT
lib.mydata.value = 470
```

**HTML Template:**

```
<f:render partial="mypartial" arguments="{dataitem: lib.mydata}" />
```

**HTML Partial:**

```
<section id="mypartial">
    <div class="xy">
      <a href="index.php?data={dataitem}">mehr ...</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: it worked with 
page.10 {
  variables {
    mydata = TEXT
    mydata.value = 471
  }
and 
<f:render partial="mypartial" arguments="{dataitem: mydata}" />

Answer (score 1):

Please use TypoScript typolink for generating Links!

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.mydata" />
```

With TypoScript

```
lib.mydata = TEXT
lib.mydata.value = mehr ...
lib.mydata.typolink.additionalParams = &data=470
```

Or use the typolink viewhelper

```
<f.link.page pageUid="1" additionalParams="{data:470}">mehr ...</f:link.page>
```

(untested)